# JSF Primefaces treeView inner component not rendered properly on treeNode other than root

Tags: jsf, primefaces, treeview, xhtml

I am trying to create Primefaces <p: treeView> with <p: textEditor> inside each <p: treeNode>. The problem is that <p: textEditor> only renders correctly in the root of <p: treeView>. On the other hand, <p: inputText> renders correctly on every <p: treeNode>.

[image]

my xhtml:

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>

</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="main_form" style="width: 100%;">
        <p:outputPanel style="width: 100%; height: 100%;overflow: auto;display: block">
            <p:tree id="commentsTree" value="#{commentsTreeManagedBean.root}" var="comment" style="width: 100%;">
                <p:treeNode>
                    <p:inputText value="#{comment.content}"/>
                    <p:textEditor widgetVar="editor2" value="#{comment.content}" height="300" style="margin-bottom:10px" placeholder="Enter your content">
                        <f:facet name="toolbar">
                            <span class="ql-formats">
                                <button class="ql-bold"></button>
                                <button class="ql-italic"></button>
                                <button class="ql-underline"></button>
                                <button class="ql-strike"></button>
                            </span>
                            <span class="ql-formats">
                                <select class="ql-font"></select>
                                <select class="ql-size"></select>
                            </span>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:textEditor>

                </p:treeNode>
            </p:tree>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

</ui:composition>

thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to report PrimeFaces bugs, please use https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/new?labels=defect&template=defect_report.md&title=Component%3A+Title

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know it was a bug, i thought it was me doing something wrong. Bug reported: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/6465